# Getting ID of new record after insert

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic, ado

I'm just getting my head around insert statements today after getting sick of cheating with Dreamweaver's methods to do this for so long now (please don't laugh).

One thing I'm trying to figure out is how to get the ID value of a newly inserted record so I can redirect the user to that page if successful.

I have seen some examples which talk about stored procedures, but they're double dutch for me at the moment and I'm yet to learn about these, let alone how to use these from within my web pages.

**Summary**

How do I, using my code below retrieve the record ID for what the user has just inserted.

**Workflow**

Using a HTML form presented on an ASP page (add.asp), a user will submit new information which is inserted into a table of a database (treebay_transaction).

On pressing submit, the form data is passed to another page (add_sql.asp) which takes the submitted data along with additional information, and inserts it into the required table.

If the insert is successful, the id value of the new record (stored in the column `treebay_transaction_id`) needs to be extracted to use as part of a querystring before the user is redirected to a page showing the newly inserted record (view.asp?id=value).

**Sample code - add_sql.asp**

```
<!--#include virtual="/Connections/IntranetDB.asp" -->
...
<html>
<body>
<%
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString = MM_IntranetDB_STRING
conn.Open ConnectionString
...
sql="INSERT INTO treebay_transaction (treebay_transaction_seller,treebay_transaction_start_date,treebay_transaction_expiry_date,treebay_transaction_title,treebay_transaction_transaction_type,treebay_transaction_category,treebay_transaction_description,treebay_transaction_status)"
sql=sql & " VALUES "
sql=sql & "('" & CurrentUser & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & timestampCurrent & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & timestampExpiry & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("treebay_transaction_title") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("treebay_transaction_transaction_type") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("treebay_transaction_category") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xhtml1") & "',"
sql=sql & "'3')"

on error resume next
conn.Execute sql,recaffected
if err<>0 then
%>
<h1>Error!</h1>
<p>
...error text and diagnostics here...
</p>
<%
else
    ' this is where I should be figuring out what the new record ID is
    recordID = ??
    ' the X below represents where that value should be going
    Response.Redirect("index.asp?view.asp?id='" & recordID & "'")
end if
conn.close
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not use the code above as a sample, it has SQL Injection vulnerabilities that usually end up killing IIS and ASP reputation where really its all user code.

Comment: As CarlosAg said! I know my code has SQL injection issues, and that's the next thing I intend to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this after your execute statement and before you close your connection:

```
lsSQL = "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NewID"
Set loRs = loConn.Execute(lsSQL)
llID = loRs.Fields("NewID").value
```

I pulled it from here:
http://www.kamath.com/tutorials/tut007_identity.asp

Comment: Thanks for that lead. Using an MS SQL 2005 server, and I can make my resulting SQL string work without a problem via SQL Server Manager. Whenever I try it via the ASP page in question (add_sql.asp) it returns a 424 - object required error. I've placed a sample of the page in its latest form at http://bit.ly/d3Cr1I. If you could take a look and figure out where I've messed up it would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use NextRecordSet since you are only returning one recordset? I don't remember as it has been a long time since I have used this. 

p.s. Also you really should take note of what people are saying in here about sanitizing your data before using directly in query. You are leaving yourself wide open for problems.

Comment: This could cause major issues if there are other things going on in your database, such as triggers.

Answer (score 4):

Build your `sql` variable as you have been. Let's make one trip to the DB instead of two. We'll use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` right in the same statement(s) as the `INSERT` to avoid many trips to the database.

Add this when building your SQL statement:

```vb
sql=sql & "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As NewTreebayTransactionID"

'now execute the insert and receive the ID in one Execute statement.
 set newTransactionResults = conn.Execute(sql)

 'here is our new ID.
 recordID = newTransactionResults("NewTreebayTransactionID")
```

As soon as that's done:

- sanitize your data inputs from your user
- use parameterized statements

Comment: Thanks for that, is there any reason why that would return an Expected end of statement error before sql in the set line? Full example of latest result & error generated at http://bit.ly/c6Xjyt

Comment: @thewinchster: indeed, perhaps remove the RecordsAffected parameter for now?

Comment: Yes, that helped somewhat but kept throwing up object exceptions. Finally added 'Set newRS = newRS.NextRecordSet()' after reading the link provided by spinon, and now working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        objConn.Open "DSN=connectionName"
        rs.CursorLocation = 3
        rs.Open "treebay_transaction", objConn, 3, 3

        rs.AddNew fieldlist,values 'see link bellow to see how to fill this
        rs.Update
        bookmark = rs.absolutePosition  ' First, store the location of you cursor
        rs.Requery                      ' Next, update your recordset with the data from the database
        rs.absolutePosition = bookmark  ' Finally, change your cursor back
        recordID = rs("ID")
```

rs.AddNew documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_addnew.asp

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the database you are using, in SQL Server you can get the @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() see: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

But one thing I want to warn you, the code above has SEVERE security vulnerabilities, namely SQL Injection attack, please stay away from concatenating strings that are coming from users, you should use command paramaters.

Answer (score 1):

look to @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY or IDENT_CURRENT

This makes the assumption that your ID field is an IDENTITY INSERT field.  Also consider ramifications of the various options listed, as each one acts and performs slightly differently.

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Functions_-_@@IDENTITY,_SCOPE_IDENTITY,_IDENT_CURRENT

Answer (score 0):

With the same transaction :

```
Const adUseServer = 2
Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "DSN=connectionName"
  Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  oRS.CursorLocation = aduseserver
  oRS.CursorType = adopenkeyset
  oRS.LockType = adlockoptimistic
  oRS.Open "treebay_transaction", oConn
  if oRS.eof then
    oRS.AddNew
    oRS("treebay_transaction_seller") = CurrentUser
...
    oRS.Update
    recordID = oRS("treebay_transaction_id")
  end if
  oRS.Close
  set oRS = nothing
oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
```